# The Importance of Initial Conditions in Autoregressive Modeling

Tags: time-series, classification, arima, autoregressive

I am developing an algorithm to classify time series by using autoregressive modeling. I have used the following two alternative methods, after fitting an AR(p) model to time series:
    Method 1: Using  p model coefficients 
    Method 2: Using p model coefficients plus first p data values
It seems that Method 2 is better than Method 1.  My rationale for including the first p data values in Method 2 was the reality that we loose information in the first data p data values when we compute estimated values based on AR(p) modeling,
My problem is this: I tried to substantiate this idea from literature; I searched hundreds of papers along with tens of books, but have not met any document that mentions the role of initial conditions in AR or broadly ARIMA modeling. Do you suggest any?..